# why is not showing data in dropdown

Tags: angular

I having an issue my data are not displayed my api also working fine but data are not displaying.

```
countries: {};

ngOnInit() {
    this.getCountry()
}

 <div class="form-group">
<select formControlName="country" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value)">
  <option value="">Select country...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country?.data?.phonecode}}</option>
</select>
```

```
getCountry(){
    this._country.getCountries().subscribe((res: any) =>{
        this.countries = res.data;
        
    });
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you add content of res.data please.

Comment: i have added the json pls check @NTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response `data`  type is `array` according your `JSON` file  and you are saving it in type `{}`.

You should change typescript

```
countries: any[] = [];
```

No need to put `any` in method , here it is updated code

```
getCountry(){
    this._country.getCountries().subscribe((res) =>{
        this.countries = res.data;
    });
}
```

And third point was about `Phonecode` . Now just do looping on countries array.

**NOTE** : In countries array we have now all countries , because we retrieved them from `JSON` using `res.data`

**HTML**

```
<select formControlName="country" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value)">
  <option value="">Select country...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.phonecode}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

phonecode property is inside the country not country.data so change your select with the following

```
<select formControlName="country" class="form-control" (change)="onChangeCountry($event.target.value)">
  <option value="">Select country...</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.phonecode}}</option>
</select>
```